# How to use LABEL statement in SAS Arrays? Is it even possible?

Tags: sas

I am trying to use Tranwrd function to remove a standard text(": Colon") from multiple variables' labels. So I used array. But it doesn't work. I read somewhere that LABEL statement has to have an actual variable name listed. But I am not sure. Following is the sample code:

```
    data test;
     CG1DF=1;
     CG2DF=2;
     CG3DF=3;
     CG4DF=4;
     CG5DF=5;
     label CG1DF="Sample1 :Colon"
           CG2DF="Sample2 :Colon"
           CG3DF="Sample3 :Colon"
           CG4DF="Sample4 :Colon"
           CG5DF="Sample5 :Colon";
    run;
    
    proc report data=test; run;
    
    data final;
     set test;
     /*label CG1DF=tranwrd(vlabel(CG1DF),": Colon","");*/
     array CG(*) CG1DF CG2DF CG3DF CG4DF CG5DF;
     do i=1 to dim(CG);
        label CG(i)=tranwrd(vlabel(CG(i)),": Colon","");
     end;
    run;

    It throws this error:
    33          label CG(i)=tranwrd(vlabel(CG(i)),": Colon","");
                _
                73
                76
    ERROR 73-322: Expecting an =.
```

I understand, other way is to create a macro variable of required variables and use proc datasets. But I am curious to know why this doesn't work.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use arrays in label statements, but you can build the label statement using SQL and save it into a single macro variable:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select cats(name, '=', '"', tranwrd(label," :Colon",""), '"')
    into :labels separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where    libname = 'WORK'
         AND memname = 'TEST'
         AND name LIKE 'CG%DF'
    ;
quit;
```

This creates the following macro variable `&labels.`:

```
CG1DF="Sample1" CG2DF="Sample2" CG3DF="Sample3" CG4DF="Sample4" CG5DF="Sample5"
```

You can then apply it using your method of choice.

```
data final;
   set test;
   label &labels.;
run;
```

Or:

```
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    modify test;
        &labels.;
quit;
```

As to why, your guess is as good as mine. Since it's a very widespread statement that can be used in nearly any PROC or DATA step, my guess is it does not support arrays out of sheer compatibility with all the different ways and places it can be used. I would recommend putting this in as a feature request to SAS Tech Support if it's something you think would be very valuable.

Comment: yes , thanks for this. I am already using this approach as an alternate. But wasn't sure why we can't use arrays.

Comment: Tom has a much better answer to this than I do. I'd say he's got your reason why :)

Answer (score 1):

An ARRAY is a method to reference a variable dynamically **at run time** via an index into list of variables.

Trying to use it to reference variables during the data step setup time does not make much sense.   Certainly not worth the development effort to modify the syntax of the SAS language to support that.

Comment: Thank you Tom, appreciate your response!